# Dynamic Component Loopback 4

Tags: typescript, loopback4

Is there any way to build a plugin loading system using Loopback 4 Component architecture. The use case : We should be able to enable / disable plugins run time, without restarting the server / recompiling the entire loopback application.

I was looking around the Components in loopback 4 and all of the documentation deals with how to build and Compile it statically. Especially when it comes to the fact that we create components using typescript and compile it into js, it may become harder. I was thinking , some one else must have faced this and solved this potentially ? The best i came across is a library https://github.com/c9/architect , but since it is in js, it may not be straight forward to use it in loopback as typescript ?